# find and replace value

Tags: matlab, find, nan

I have a structured array (1x1) called 'Data' which has 3 fields. Each field contains a vector of data.

The following code is used to replace values which vary by greater than `0.2` with the value next to it with `NaN`. However, is it possible to alter this code so that the value which alters by `0.2` does not change to `NaN` but changes to the value which it was compared to?

```
for i=1:3;
    I{i} = find(diff(Data.(Names{i}))>0.2); 
    Data.(Names{i})(I{i}+1)=NaN;
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are comparing an element with the previous element. If the difference is greater than 0.2 then replace this element with the previous one?

Then you're almost there. Assign the value of the previous elements like this:

```
Data.(Names{i})(I{i}+1)=Data.(Names{i})(I{i})
```